# Why CAML doesn't return all Fields/values from sharepoint List?

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, sharepoint, caml

I have a Sharepoint list which have columns like : CopmanyName, Add1, Add2 Country, State/Province. State/Province have a condition to enter only when country is as selected as America or Canada, So few records in SharePoint have this field(ows_State) as empty.

Now I am trying to get the records from SharePoint using webservices, CAML query, the problem that I am facing is that if the field (State/Provice) is empty then the CAML doesn't get its information, in-fact the field name itself is not added in the z:row element of XML.
I have this field bound to a gridView on front-end (as Eval) and if element ows_State is not found in XML then it throws error.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated,

If nothing works then probably I'll have to check and dynamically add this field.

```
var StateElement = doc.Element(rs + "data").Element(z + "row").Attribute("ows_State_x002f_Province");
                if (StateElement == null)
                {
                    doc.Element(rs + "data").Element(z + "row").Add(new XAttribute("ows_State_x002f_Province", " "));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar problem.  The thing is, If your field is empty, CAML won't return you that field in your XML.

The solution I made was to check XML for attribute's existence, If it's not there, add it manually.

Check this out :

http://naimishpandya.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/how-to-add-xml-attribute-to-an-existing-xml-node-in-c-c-sharp/

You can also achieve it through LINQ To XML.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/be75108d-2265-41f0-8a22-f2ecc025cf53

Comment: Thanks Nick, this seems G**, Microsoft should have think something about this let me quickly try the tutorial you mentioned and I'll post you back, well the code I added in the end also works, but only if the xml have a single z:row, You have any idea how it could be achieved using LINQ to serach thru all the the z:row elements and add it(If missing).
Thanks once again.

Comment: I have updated the link of Microsoft which does the same.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you. Also if you satisfy then please mark this as answer. Thanks...Naimish

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: This works finally :

foreach(XElement zrow in doc.Root.Elements(z + "row").Where(u => u.Attribute("ows_State_x002f_Province")==null).ToList())
{
     zrow.Add(new XAttribute("ows_State_x002f_Province", " "));
}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(XElement zrow in doc.Root.Elements(z + "row").Where(u => u.Attribute("ows_State_x002f_Province")==null).ToList()) 

{ 
     zrow.Add(new XAttribute("ows_State_x002f_Province", " ")); 
}
```